# Using ng-if to show and hide elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a search bar and a last viewed list in my main view, what i am trying to do is hide the last viewed list when the user starts typing in the search bar and unhide it when the search bar is empty. With the current code i am using it displays the last viewed list at first and hides when the user starts typing however it is never unhidden when the search box is cleared.

I have determined that when the user clears the search box the query no longer equals {}, which causes ng-if to show the last viewed list, but it equals {$: ""} which causes ng-if to keep it hidden.

```
<ion-view view-title="Office Finder">
<!-- Favourites button -->
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button icon ion-android-star" ui-sref="Favourites">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <!-- Search function starts here -->
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" id="search-criteria" placeholder="City, Country or Office Name" ng-model="query[queryBy]">
        </label>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <!-- Search function ends here -->


    <ion-content has-subheader>
        <!-- Main content starts here -->
        <!-- ng-show hides the list of offices and displays them when the user starts searching  -->
        <ion-list ng-if="query[queryBy]">
        <!-- Creates each item through collection-repeat and is filtered by the query linked to the search field -->
        <!-- ng-click opens the modal that will have the enlarged office address and the map of the office -->
            <ion-item class="item-text-wrap item-icon-right" id="output" collection-repeat="office in offices|filter:query[queryBy]" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(office.Lat, office.Long); lastview(office.id);">
                <!-- Outputs all the data from offices.json -->
                <h3 id="LocName">{{office.LocationName}}</h3>
                <!-- the span prevents null data from being output causing empty space to be displayed -->
                <p id="details"><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine1">{{office.LocAddressLine1}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine2">, {{office.LocAddressLine2}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCity">, {{office.LocCity}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCountryDescription">, {{office.LocCountryDescription}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocZipPostalCode">, {{office.LocZipPostalCode}}</span></p>

                <!-- Creates the favourite icon on each list item, when the star is clicked the togglefav function is run -->
                <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
            </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


    <ion-list id="cont">
        <!-- Last view offices list -->
        <div ng-if="!query[queryBy]">
                <h3 class="title" id="text">Last Viewed</h3>
            <!-- the filter with this collection repeat runs the function ifinfav2 which only displays items in the localstorage -->
                <ion-item id="fav" class="item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="office in offices|filter:ifinfav2" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(office.Lat, office.Long);">
                <h3>{{office.LocationName}}</h3>
                <p id="details"><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine1">{{office.LocAddressLine1}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine2">, {{office.LocAddressLine2}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCity">, {{office.LocCity}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCountryDescription">, {{office.LocCountryDescription}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocZipPostalCode">, {{office.LocZipPostalCode}}</span></p>
                <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
                </ion-item>
        </div>
        </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The query i am using creates an object then uses that object to search through everything in the array.

```
  $scope.query = {};
  $scope.queryBy = '$';
```

Comment: Can you use `ng-show` or `ng-hide`, with one toggle variable.

Comment: ng-show/hide gives me the same problem but it also gives me a large scrollable area when the last viewed list is hidden even though there isn't anything to scroll through

Comment: Write like: `$scope.query = { queryBy: true}` and in the event of textchange write: '$scope.query.queryBy = !$scope.query.queryBy'

Comment: could my problem be the first ng-if in the main view hiding all of the elements under it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to this:

```
ng-if="query[queryBy] != ''"
```